# need to split "date" command ouput in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I want to split date command output and extract time zone difference and represent that time difference in terms of 30 min.
I tried this:

```
date -R | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'
```

I got the output -0530
This means 5 hours and 30 min difference from GMT. Now I want to convert this -0530 in to -11. So what logic should I use in shell command?

Comment: just try adding 5:30 like `date -R | awk 'NF>1{print ($NF + 530)}'` or `date -R | awk 'NF>1{print ($NF + $NF)}'`?

Comment: What's the logic for that timezone offset conversion? Are you multiplying by 2 or subtracting a fixed 5:30? What timezone is 5:30 before than GMT? -0500 is eastern North America and western South America.

Answer (score 1):

```
date -R | awk '{tz=$NF;ew=substr(tz,1,1);h=substr(tz,1,3)*2;m=ew substr(tz,4,2)/30;print h + m}'
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

Edited to work with omitted sign

```
date -R | awk '{tz=$NF;l=length(tz);m=substr(tz,l-1,2)/30;h=substr(tz,l-3,2)*2;ew=l>4?ew=substr(tz,1,1):"+";print (ew h)+(ew m)}'
```

Comment: Thanks tomc, this logic only works if time zone value difference value is negative. e.g. if timezone is 0500 then output comes as 100 instead of 10.

Comment: my apologies, I added the link because that is where I read the sign was mandatory. but I do not have a ready source of positive time zone offsets ,so that was a risk. Hopefully you will have adapted the example to accommodate positive offsets before my holiday cheer has worn off enough for me to look at it again

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate things.

```
tz=$(date '+%z'); echo "${tz:0:1}$(( 2 * ${tz:1:2} + ${tz:3} ))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't, and instead use a different tool. In the `perl` module `Time::Piece` you have `tzoffset` which returns the current timezone skew in seconds.

Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 

$ENV{'TZ'}='GMT-6';
my $now = localtime; 
#find number of 30m differences; 
print $now -> tzoffset / 60 / 30;
```

You can also use variants of `strftime` to print time formatted to your liking:

```
print $now -> strftime("%c");
```

This can be cut down into a one liner if so desired:

```
perl -MTime::Piece 'print localtime -> tzoffset / 60 / 30'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU date, you could perform math on time/date values (in UTC):

```
$ date -uR -d "now";  date -uR -d "now -60 min"
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 20:34:17 +0000
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 19:34:17 +0000
```

A time of `-5:30` is `-330` min:

```
$ date -uR -d "now";  date -uR -d "now -330 min"
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 20:34:55 +0000
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 15:04:55 +0000
```

That could be further moved by the time zone:

```
$  TZ=America/New_York date -R -d "now"; TZ=America/New_York date -R -d "now -330 min"
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 15:34:26 -0500
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 10:04:26 -0500
```

That is the local time (now) subtracting 5 hours and 30 minutes.

However, what is a time zone of -5:30?

I know that [India is +5:30](http://www.worldtimezone.com/wtz014.php) and there are some (very few) [places that are +11:00](http://www.worldtimezone.com/utc/utc+1100.html).
But I fail to find any -5:30 and -11:00 seems just odd.